# Using Strings from resources in List.

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-resources

I'm new to Android and I'm having a problem using String variables from resources in my code. I tried a couple of solutions found on the internet and Android API Guides, but they didn't work in this specific case, could also be me not using them correctly.

To be more specific, I have a Master/Detail flow activity and I would like to use resource strings as item names for multilanguage purposes, but I have a problem with recovering actual strings.
The error I get is:

> Cannot resolve method 'getString()'

Here is my code based on android studio dummy file

```
public class Categories {

public static List<CatName> ITEMS = new ArrayList<CatName>();

static {
    String temp = getString(R.string.cat_n1);
    addItem(new CatName("1", temp);
}

private static void addItem(CatName item) {
    ITEMS.add(item);
}

public static class CatName {
    public String id;
    public String name;

    public FieldCat(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

   @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the resource. Try this,

```
getResources().getString(R.string.cat_n1);
```

`getString(int resId)`: Return a localized string from the application's package's default string table.

`getResources().getString(int id)`: Returns the string value associated with a particular resource ID. It will be stripped of any styled text information.

Answer (score 0):

Try using it with a constructor passing the context and calling getstring on that

```
public class Categories {

public static List<CatName> ITEMS = new ArrayList<CatName>();

public Categories(Context ct)
{
   String temp = ct.getString(R.string.abc_action_bar_home_description);
   addItem(new CatName("1", temp));
}

private static void addItem(CatName item) {
    ITEMS.add(item);
}

public static class CatName {
    public String id;
    public String name;

public CatName(String id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
}}
```